# In composition of two mappings, can the outer mapping access the arguments of the inner mapping?

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

In composition of two mappings, can the outer mapping access the arguments of the inner mapping?

1. Here is an example to illustrate my question and my thought.

   E.g. $f: \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is taking
   sum, i.e.  $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) =  \sum_i x_i$. Note here $n$ can
   vary in $\mathbb N$.

   $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is to further divide the sum by the
   sample size, to get the sample mean , i.e. $g(f(x_1, \dots, x_n)) =
   \sum_i x_i/n$.

   Is $g(f(x_1, \dots, x_n))$ a composition of the two mappings $f$ and
   $g$?

   I think that in a  composition of two mappings, the outer mapping 
   only acts on the codomain of the inner mapping, and thus shouldn't
   know the input to the inner mapping. In the example, $g$ should not
   know  $n$. So it doesn't make sense to  compose $f$ and $g$.

   A revision would be $f: \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} \mathbb R^n \to
   \mathbb  R \times \mathbb N$ with $f(x_1, \dots, x_n) =  [\sum_i
   x_i, n]^T$, and $g: \mathbb  R \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ with
   $g(x,n) = x/n$. Only then the composition of $f$ and $g$ would make
   sense to me. What would you think?
2. The question comes from statistics, where $f$ is a "statistic" which
   takes in a sample of size $n$, and $n$ can vary in $\mathbb N$, and
   $g$ is a transform on the statistic. To see more of my specific
   question, please refer to
   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114240/can-the-measurable-mapping-in-the-definition-of-complete-statistics-depend-on-sa.

   Here at math.se, I ask a more general question for general math. In
   the link to stats.se, I asked a specific question in
   statistics. I understand that the answers to the two may be related and different.

Thanks.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning. You cannot compose the original $g$ and $f$ because $g$ doesn't know $n$. Your revision solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your definitions. First, your definition of the domain of $f$ is missing. If you mean the domain to be the set of $\infty$-tuples in which only finitely many entries are nonzero, you should say so. In the way you wrote your domain, I would have asked you what your inclusion of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ was. I did assume that your union was *not* a disjoint union, but involved inclusions of smaller spaces into largers.

As you describe $g$, it is not a function, since its value depends on the particular $\mathbb R^n$ you want to consider the argument to lie in. You *could* make a well-defined $g$ that counted up the number of nonzero entries in your $\infty$-tuple, and divided by that number, and this would certainly be well-defined, but neither linear nor continuous.

I’m having trouble understanding your revision, too, again for the reason that you don’t know which $\mathbb R^n$ an element of your “union” lies in.

Comment: Thanks. The domain of $f$ is the union of all finite-length real sequences. Does my notation $f: \cup_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ in the post make sense now? $\cup_{i \in \mathbb N} \mathbb R^n$ is a disjoint union, because $\mathbb R^n$ is the set of all length-$n$ real sequences.

Comment: I don't understand the objection. As long as $f$ assigns a well-defined value to each element of its domain, then it is a valid function. The domain is $D = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{R}^n$, which is a disjoint union. A given $v \in D$ lies in exactly one $\mathbb{R}^n$, so there is nothing wrong with a function with domain $D$ which uses the value of $n$. Analogously, a function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ is free to assign a value that depends on whether the argument is rational or irrational.

Comment: Ah, I see that, being an algebraist, I assumed that you wanted the domain of $f$ to be a group, in which two arguments could be added. So I looked at your (disjoint) union and misinterpreted it as what we call a direct limit of the $\mathbb R^n$’s. As a disjoint union, your domain supports very well the function you described in your revision. I’ll leave my “answer” up to show how preconceptions can lead one astray.

Answer (score 0):

The form of expression ("access the arguments of the inner mapping") suggests to me that you're bringing a programmer's perspective to this subject.  Your formulation in #1 is the correct idea, but you should probably introduce two auxiliary functions s and d as follows: for any x in the disjoint union, d(x) is the dimension of the unique Cartesian space containing x and s(x) is the sum of the components of x.  Then your f(x) is simply (s(x),d(x)) and your g computes the desired ratio from any pair (r,n) of a real r and a natural number n.  That's too tediously pedantic for normal mathematical discourse, but comfy for functional programmers ;-)